# How can i create a multidimensional arrays using PostreSQL and is PHP able to handle it?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

Hey,
I want to collect data from three tables but i don't really know how to do that, because i want to create multidimensional arrays and use them with php. Im new to pgsql so i dont really know what the limits are :)
So could anybody show me how to create a simple pgsql array?

thanks

Comment: You don't really create "arrays" in RDBMSes. What do you want these multidimensional arrays to look like? What are you using in PHP to connect to the db?

Comment: The usage of arrays inside a database is very often a sign of a bad database design. Could you post some sample data (including table definitions) and the expected output based on that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgre there are array-datatypes (array versions of almost every plain datatype). But I wouldn't recommend using them, specifically **not** in combination with PHP. Because with the current database-functions it will return the array as a string. Also it kind of defies the purpose of a relational database where an array should be considered as a number of rows of one column. Not a single row of a single column.

To try to answer your question. You problaby should consider the "deepest" element of your multidimensional array as a "row" from the database. where several columns specify the path it has to take to get to the value.

Example:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

  $multi_array[$row->base][$row->layer] = $row->value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a database will return a flat array of condensed results. So you most-likely can't do a single query to end up with nested items the way you want. However, I haven't worked with PostgreSQL.

My advice would be to do multiple queries to get the data you need, and to then place them into the desired configuration.

Maybe someone who has worked with Postgre can confirm?